# background-size performance

Tags: html, css

I need to implement image previews via thumbnails. Now I'm not certain how to implement it.

One option would be to do it straight with CSS, so something like this:

```
.thumbnail {
  background-image: url(path/to/image);
  background-size: 300px, 400px;
}
```

Is that practical? Are there any performance issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "realize"?

Comment: If you had 50 images with the size 5000x5000 and you wanted to display them in a gallery on one page, that code of yours would definitely lock up most of your visitors' computers, before getting even as far as rendering 7-8 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scale image in CSS to be smaller than it it actually is, browser still have to download the same amount of data. You should create separate file with the thumbnail.

Answer (score -1):

With images, you need to focus on three things: size, format and the src attribute.

**Image size**

Oversized images take longer to load, so it’s important that you keep your images as small as possible. Use image editing tools to:

Crop your images to the correct size. For instance, if your page is 570px wide, resize the image to that width. Don’t just upload a 2000px-wide image and set the width parameter (width=”570”). This slows your page load time and creates a bad user experience.
Reduce color depth to the lowest acceptable level.
Remove image comments.

**Image format**

JPEG is your best option.
PNG is also good, though older browsers may not fully support it.
GIFs should only be used for small or simple graphics (less than 10×10 pixels, or a color palette of 3 or fewer colors) and for animated images.
Do not use BMPs or TIFFs.

**Src attribute**

Once you’ve got the size and format right, make sure the code is right too. In particular, avoid empty image src codes.

In HTML, the code for an image includes this:

When there’s no source in the quotation marks, the browser makes a request to the directory of the page or to the actual page itself. This can add unnecessary traffic to your servers and even corrupt user data.

Pro Tip: Take time to re-size your images before uploading them. And always include the src attribute with a valid URL.

To ensure your images load quickly, consider adding the WP Smush.it plugin to your website.

from: http://blog.crazyegg.com/2013/12/11/speed-up-your-website/